# Load content md-tabs asynchronous

Tags: angularjs, cordova, tabs, angular-material

I am developing a cross-platform app for Ios, use Cordova and Angular Material.

My home page has three tabs and in each tab the content will be load from Web service.

My problem is when app was build in Ios, each time I switch between tabs, the transition is not smooth. It has delay time to load data.

Is there any way to load data in each tab asynchronous in order to switch transition will be perform immediately and content data will be update later.

Comment: Is it possible to load all content in one go and pass only the data required for the tab content when the tab is selected?

Comment: sorry but i don't exactly understand what you mean. You mean when app load, I will load all data for all tabs and when a tab is selected, I will update this data for this tab ?

Comment: Yes, load all data for all tabs at startup. When a tab is selected pass only the data required for the content to the tab content. I can put more detail in an answer if you prefer.

Comment: Yes, please. All help is welcome. I am new in Angular js

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example expanding from my comment - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/XjXWAG?editors=1010#0)

It demonstrates the ability to pass specific data from all data to specific tab content. There are many other ways of achieving the same result.

Markup

```
<div ng-cloak="" class="tabsdemoDynamicHeight" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController as vm">
  <md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" md-selected="vm.selectedIndex">
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <content data="vm.allData[vm.selectedIndex]"></content>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <content data="vm.allData[vm.selectedIndex]"></content>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="three">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <content data="vm.allData[vm.selectedIndex]"></content>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller("MyController", function () {
  this.allData = [
    "John", "Paul", "George"
  ];
})

.directive("content", function() {
  return {
    template: "<div>{{data}}</div>",
    scope: {data: "="}
  }
});
```